# Need help with cropped pdf images

Tags: graphics, pdf, crop, pdf-a

I cropped figures (*.pdf) from scientific PDF articles with the excellent Krop tool by Armin Straub:

http://arminstraub.com/software/krop

Everything worked fine until I needed to convert my final thesis from the usual PDF format to PDF/A-1b format for archiving. Suddenly, the surrounding full page around the images (that is, the text around the cropped picture) becomes visible in the PDF/A output. Maybe because this format does not support transparency.

Is their any way to tell LaTex to not embed the whole page of the image into the document, but only the cropped part that has been "marked" by Krop? Something like a "clipping area" or anything like this?

Comment: I would try a different graphics editor.  You should be able to remove layers one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

From the PDF/A rules:

> Transparent objects and layers (Optional Content Groups) are not
>   permitted.

[Link](http://www.pdfa.org/2011/08/pdfa-%E2%80%93-a-look-at-the-technical-side/)

Try using a different cropping tool that removes the margins rather than moving them to an Alpha layer for transparency.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: There is an auto-crop function in ImageJ I believe - or you can do it manually in any image editing program.

Answer (score 1):

Run your output pdf through the following command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

No. When a page of a PDF is included in a PDF by any of the TeX engines/device drivers it is always included *completely*; no destructive cropping or other manipulation is done.