# PDF or PDF/A to Latex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, pdf-a

I have made a sketch in Visio.
I plan to save it to `.pdf` for use with `pdflatex`.

I have the option of saving as PDF/A-1 (a or b not specified).

Would I want to make a habit of saving these images as PDF/A,
or is this completely superfluous for the purpose.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, pdf/a-1 requires that the fonts are embedded and general pdf does not require it (nowadays most do), so I think I'd test both and go with the one where the fonts are embedded into the pdf, just to be on the safe side, as some if the fonts in MS might not be available in latex.

Comment: Noted: If contains text, use PDF/A? (PDF/A is the font embedder.)

Comment: The one that embeds the fonts.  If no fonts are used, I'm guessing both are the same? Haven't looked at the details. I've only noted that, say,  word does not embed certain fonts into pdf unless you use pdf/a

Comment: Save as a normal PDF should do just fine. Also, latex works with pdf/a. I have had done this before.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309876/need-help-with-cropped-pdf-images?s=1|0.3167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF/A is a standard for long-time archiving. It requires that all resources are embedded like fonts and color profiles. Also it restricts the language features. Advanced features like transparency or interactive features (JavaScript, some annotations, ...) are forbidden, which might be displayed differently in different viewers.

A reasonable algorithm would be:

1. If features are known and needed like transparency, which violate PDF/A,
   then goto 4.
2. Export via PDF/A.
3. Review the generated PDF file. Are all needed features present, is the
   PDF file viewed and imported correctly?

   - If yes, then the generated PDF file is very likely the better choice,
     more robust and better suited to be used in later years.
     Done.
   - Else, goto 4.
4. Export via PDF. Done.